# Visual Studio not Compiling Sometimes

Tags: visual-studio, iis, windows-server-2008

I am using an ASP.NET site on a ISS Server on a Windows Server 2008 that compiles a solution for me In the following matter:

```
Dim command = "devenv ""Solution.sln"" /build Debug /project ""Project.vbproj""  /projectconfig Debug /out ""logBuildUpdateInfoprim.log"""
Dim cmdsi = New ProcessStartInfo(command)
cmdsi.Arguments = arg
cmdsi.CreateNoWindow = True
cmdsi.UserName = "user"
cmdsi.Password = "pass"
cmdsi.UseShellExecute = False
Dim cmd = Process.Start(cmdsi)
cmd.WaitForExit()
```

The "user" and "pass" are for a system adminitrator
I also set the Identity of the site's Application Pool as the "user"

And it works for about a few weeks and then at the next compilation the devenv process just sits as 0% processor and ~2Mb of RAM. And it sits indefinitely.
The only way to fix this is to log as the "user" in windows, close the devenv process manually and then open Visual Studio. After that I can logoff from the windows server and the website works again for a few weeks.

(I am using Visual Studio Community)

I suspect that Visual Studio needs to be open so it activates the Visual Studio account, or maybe it's a issue with the windows server. Anyway, it's a real pain to periodically have to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I did not find any answers on how to bypass the login in Visual Studio I used

> msbuild.exe

as a workaround.